# Map a 2D Vector to a Rectangle

Tags: math, geometry

I'm not very good at maths. However, during game development, I need to map a normalized 2D vector, let's say vector `a`, to a point on the edge of a rectangle. Vector `a` represents a direction from the centre of the rectangle, you can assume that the rectangle's centre is at the origin (`0, 0`). I then need to change the length of this vector to lie on the edge of the rectangle without rotating it.

The pseudo-code might look like this:

```
Vector2D mapVectorToRectangle(Vector2D a, float rectWidth, float rectHeight) {
    //Do calculations and return value.
}
```

How would I implement this in pseudo-code/Java?

Comment: What do you mean by `position of vector`?

Comment: @MBo That's a good point, I'm used to thinking of vectors as coordinates. Updated to use a better word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pseudocode:

```
Vector2D mapVectorToRectangle(Vector2D a, float rectWidth, float rectHeight) {
  return a/max(abs(a.x)/rectWidth, abs(b.y)/rectHeight)/2
}
```

Comment: Does function returns single scalar value? What is result for `a={1,1}` and rect 2x1? What is result for `a={-2,1}` and square 2x2?  (perhaps, I don't understand the problem properly)

Comment: @MBo The function would not return a scalar value. The function returns a vector divided by two scalars. In this case, the vector is `a`, the first scalar is a call to `max` and the second scalar is the constant `2`.

Comment: OK, it is clear now. Are results for my example cases consistent with your wishes?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the next pseudocode for intersection of the ray from origin with direction vector `a` and origin-centered rectangle:

```
if rectWidth * Abs(a.y) < rectHeight * Abs(a.x) then
   x = Sign(a.x) * rectWidth / 2
   y = a.y * x / a.x
else
   y = Sign(a.y) * rectHeight / 2
   x = a.x * y / a.y
```